# Передача файла через сокет. Java

Tags: android, java, сокет

Необходимо передавать большие файлы через сокет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как. Сейчас есть такое:

```
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);

        short it;
        while((it = (short) fs.read()) !=-1) {
            os.write(it);
        }
        os.flush();
```

Но скорость ~36kB, что катастрофически низко. Вариант с массивом байтов кажется бредовым, т.к. 300 мб, боюсь, в оперативку не поместятся. Или я чего-то не догоняю?.

Comment: Почему вариант с массивом байт бредовый? Вы же не будете его по размеру файла делать. А например 2^10 элементов нормально будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если передавать short'ами, то это будет конечно очень долго. Если посмотреть профайлером, то основное время будет тратиться на всякий внутренний код.
Правильно передавать кусками побольше. Насколько побольше - сильно зависит от сети и оборудования.
Вот например так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream

Comment: > Если передавать short'ами

только в том случае если поток не буферизированный

Comment: Даже если буферизированный - все равно будет медленее - эти short ещё нужно с одного буфера в другой копировать.

Answer (score 3):

Уже больше 10 лет прошло, как Java NIO.2 с нами, а программисты всё ещё заставляют виртуальную машину выполнять лишние операции, в цикле читая в буфер из одного потока и записывая в другой. Просто скажите операционной системе откуда читать и куда писать и *zero copy* обеспечит вам максимально возможную скорость при минимально возможных расходах ресурсов:

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT);
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.connect(addr);

FileChannel fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r").getChannel();
fileChannel.transferTo(0, fileChannel.size(), socketChannel);
```

Comment: Ой, я некропостер!